# Is it possible to use the TURN/STUN protocol for p2p chat with python, and if so, where should I start?

Tags: python, stun, turn

I want to make a secure, asymmetrically-encrypted, and most importantly p2p, chat application. I've been researching if this could even work, and apparently, something like this can be achieved with a STUN/TURN protocol. How can I do something like this in Python, at the least, what libraries would I need to get started?

Comment: STUN/TURN are typically used to establish a p2p udp stream between devices that are located behind NAT/firewall. The trick is to poke holes in the NAT/FW and then use the holes for establishing incoming streams. This is common in VoIP, where it’s ok to use udp for the media (some packet loss is tolerable). In your case, chatting, packet loss is not acceptable, so I would not recommend this approach.

Comment: @shauli Is there any way you can send media to devices behind NAT without having to send your media through a server?

Comment: Yes. It’s called “early media”. A client behind NAT sends a few media packet to your server that has a public address. The NAT allocates an ip/port for this outbound stream and your server learns it (source ip/port). Now your server can instruct the other client to send media to this NAT port. Same thing for the second client. Now the two clients talk directly via the NAT ports. So your server is only needed for the setup phase.

Comment: @shauli Sorry, I tried googling, couldn't find anything on 'early media', perhaps there is another name for it?

Comment: try googling for "voip nat traversal". this is a good starting point: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NAT_traversal_with_session_border_controllers .

Comment: @RomanGrachev have u been able to find a library ? I see many similar questions asked, and there are answers, comments, but not concrete example of a library which can be used